# nginx: Rewrite PHP does not work

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting, nginx

I've a Suffix Proxy installed and I'm using the following rewrite with wildcard subdomain DNS on:

```
location / {
     if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
        break;
     }
}
```

My suffix proxy has the following URL format:
(subdomain and/or domain + domain extension to proxy).proxy.org/(request-uri to proxy)

I've this php code in my index.php:

```
if(preg_match('#([\w\.-]+)\.example\.com(.+)#', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $match)) {
    header('Location: http://example.com/browse.php?u=http://'.$match[1].$match[2]);
    die;
}
```

But when requested a page with a .php extension I'll get a 404 not found error:

```
http://www.php.net.proxy.org/docs.php - HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
http://www.utexas.edu.proxy.org/learn/php/ex3.php - HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

But everything else is working (also index.php is working):

```
http://php.net.proxy.org/index.php - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
http://www.php-scripts.com.proxy.org/php_diary/example2.php3 - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
http://www.utexas.edu.proxy.org/learn/php/ex3.phps - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
http://www.w3schools.com.proxy.org/html/default.asp - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Somebody has an answer? I don't know why it's not working, on apache it's working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to change that first redirection-configuration for nginx and remove the if-test.  [It's considered evil!](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Check_IF_File_Exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple layers in which this could not be working, since there is the handling of the original request, and the also the second request that is followed after you issue a redirect header.

You can put debug statements in your PHP to check the URL before the 'if' statement', inside the 'if' statement, and after it. You will soon determine if your requests for 'php' scripts are getting into this script, and how far.

Second, what do the logs show for the *second* request, to browse.php? Are the requests arriving their correctly formed?

Finally, the response codes you pasted don't tell the full story, because they don't show the redirection trail. Use a tool like 'HEAD', which comes in Perl's LWP distribution. (Packaged for many OSes). Then you'll see both the original request, and the redirection request, and the separate response code for each. Here's an example showing how google.com redirects to www.google.com:

```
$ HEAD -sSe 'http://google.com'
HEAD http://google.com
301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 21 Jun 2012 20:34:38 GMT
Location: http://www.google.com/
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Sat, 21 Jul 2012 20:34:38 GMT
Client-Date: Thu, 21 Jun 2012 20:34:29 GMT
Client-Peer: 74.125.225.104:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

HEAD http://www.google.com/
200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 21 Jun 2012 20:34:38 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Expires: -1
Client-Date: Thu, 21 Jun 2012 20:34:29 GMT
Client-Peer: 74.125.225.208:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=3d125e353127a33a:FF=0:TM=1340310878:LM=1340310878:S=D64LXQ4HKALmBZ_c; expires=Sat, 21-Jun-2014 20:34:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=61=jEiVUOmNI_XWhc78fdGMXmZVfOK-j-7S1njjY9xedBR8CIZAy0pKgAtsiIzO4MLnvFKCJ_gUm4Zx-7TKl3gmHPrEzaWbSAB52LPgZlXoFdzJb7RW_wx-UGjQRCLag0Lt; expires=Fri, 21-Dec-2012 20:34:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Alternative, you can use the Developer Tools built into Chromium/Google-Chrome. Open it up, select the Network tab, and then load google.com. You'll see a '301' request followed by a '200' requeset. You can click on the names on the left to see the full request/response headers of each.

Finally, consider rewriting your title in the form of a question to match the Q&A format of this site.

Comment: Thanks! The location was the fault, I´ve removed the location and now it works perfectly.